# Linerenderer not working as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello and I am in need of help again. I have a Linerenderer which should follow my points. The line is going up and down, but not as it should. 
Here is a gif : https://gfycat.com/ShorttermInbornHalibut
Here is my code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Manager : MonoBehaviour {

private bool click = true;

[SerializeField] private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
[SerializeField] private GraphChartFeed GCFScript;

void Update ()
{
    if(click)
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            click = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lineRenderer.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition (0, new Vector3 (GCFScript.currentXPosition, GCFScript.yPositions [GCFScript.currentYPositionIndex], 0f));
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            lineRenderer.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            click = true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

What I want it to do is just render the line to each of my points after I left click. I really need some help.

Comment: Not sure what I am looking at in that gif???  I am guessing the pink line is yours however I am unsure what exactly you are trying to do?  it maybe simpler if you made a gif with only your line, and a simple explanation in it, on what the expected behavior is.  like I click at (4,2) I expect a point here, then I click at (4,3) I expect a line from (4,2) to (4,3)  I click at (5,1)  now I expect a line from (4,3) to (5,1) or I expect the line to go from (4,2) to (4,3) to (5,1).

Comment: @Eddge I can't make a line only with the pink one, because the pink one must follow those dots. When I left click, i expect a line to be made at the current dot(the one which is the most to the right) and then the linerenderer should follow the path of the graph(going to the all coming dots).

Comment: Based off of what you said and your code, you are trying to make it so that the line renderer is deactive by default, the second you click, the lineRenderer becomes active(You could just move the setActive call into your getMouseButtonDown check). from there you are trying to update the 0 positon of the line to the x and y position of your graph.  is the graphs position in world space or is it in screen space?  if it is in screen space, then that would explain why your line skyrockets to the top of the screen(Put in a debug.log to see the value of that vector).

Comment: Another thing to note, you using currentXPosition, instead of `GCFScript.xPositions [GCFScript.currentXPosition]`